# Many CSS Selectors which are not supported in IE 6. How to over come this issue?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, internet-explorer-6

`DIV>P` Selects all `<P>` elements where the parent is a `<DIV>` element.

But this particular selector is not supported in IE 6.0. Is there any way to over come this problem? If possible a generic solution because there are many CSS DOM selectors which are not supported (`DIV>P, DIV+P` etc)

Comment: If you must support IE6, it would be much easier to just avoid having to use these selectors. When it comes to old IEs, you quite simply can't have the best of both worlds. You avoid supporting either one or the other.

Comment: Don't support IE6? Seriously, it's ancient!

Comment: Unless you're extremely masochistic, you do not want to support IE6 in this day and age, really...

Comment: Use jQuery as the easiest option.

Comment: @Ash — How does jQuery solve the problem of lack of selector support in CSS?!

Comment: I was searching for a shim.I think I found something.Try this-http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: @Quentin How do you think it does not solve it? You create a class which has the styling that you want and then you just type $('div > p').addClass('class you wrote');

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, that I know of, to overcome this. If you must support IE6 and a generic selection like `div p {}` is not enough, you either need to assign classes to the paragraph tags affected or rely on jQuery to be able to use advanced CSS selectors. You could also use vanilla JavaScript, but IE6 support might be so frustrating that you better use a JS library.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know only universal selector `*` works in IE6. so as per your scenario here I've done and tested in IE tester tool bar. all `p` element will be selected where `div` element is parent.

A Dummy HTML Code I used here.

```
<div>Simple test will not red
    <p>1st paragraph</p>
    <p>2nd paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <p>3rd paragraph will not red</p>
   <p>4th paragraph will not red</p>
  <div>Simple test will not red
    <p>1st paragraph</p>
    <p>2nd paragraph</p>
</div>
```

A CSS is:

```
div *{color:red;}
```

Here is the ***[Demo](http://jsbin.com/radalupu/1/)***.

Here is the screenshot of IE6 Browser on IE tester tool.[image]